# How to use AWS Nitro Enclave with ECS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs

I am trying to setup AWS Nitro Enclave with ECS using AWS Cloudformation but I am struggling with assigning a launch template to an ECS service.

As far as I know, we can specify a `launchType` with the value of `EC2` while creating the ECS Service but there is no way to manipulate the launch parameters.

Any help with examples will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The Nitro Enclave is part of the EC2 server. An ECS service is just a docker container running on the EC2 server. The EC2 server has to already be up and running (with things like Nitro Enclave already configured) before the ECS service is started on the server. The `launchType` parameter of the ECS Service just specifies if it should run on Fargate or EC2.

You can't configure your cluster's EC2 servers through an ECS service configuration. You would configure the EC2 servers in the ECS cluster through the cluster's [Capacity Provider](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/cluster-capacity-providers.html) configuration. Specifically, since you are using EC2 instead of Fargate, you would need to configure the capacity provider with an [EC2 auto-scaling group](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/asg-capacity-providers.html) which is configured with an EC2 launch template that handles the Nitro Enclave setup.

---

To be clear, I've never heard of anyone using Nitro Enclaves with ECS, and I don't think you can actually run ECS services inside the Nitro Enclave. At most you could have ECS services running on the same server that also has a Nitro Enclave running some other process.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you think if we needed to run a webservice which would handle about 60k requests everyday written in Python inside a Nitro Enclave, would it be performant, scalable and available? We need to have it inside an Enclave due to governmental recommendation.